# Object fields return undefiend although object set properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React native I'm trying to access the name field of my user object, but i get undefined.

When I log user i get:
{"name":"Dad","about":null,"createdAt":"2023-03-28T20:19:18.538Z","updatedAt":"2023-03-28T20:19:18.538Z","deletedAt":null}

When I log user.name or user["name"] i get:
undefined

Any help will be very much appreciated!

```
const Chat = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);
  const { messages, setMessages, currentChat, getChatData, sendMessage } = useContext(ChatsContext);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        await getChatData();
      };
      fetchData();
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, [])
  );

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setInputValue(value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    console.log(user) // {"name":"Dad","about":null,"createdAt":"2023-03-28T20:19:18.538Z","updatedAt":"2023-03-28T20:19:18.538Z","deletedAt":null}
    console.log(user.name) // undefined

    await sendMessage(inputValue);
    if (inputValue.trim() !== "") {
      const newMessage = {
        id: messages.length,
        content: inputValue,
        User: {
          name: user.name,
        }
      };
      setMessages([...messages, newMessage])
      setInputValue("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#009688" />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ChatHeader chatName={currentChat.name} />
          <FlatList
            data={currentChat.Messages}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Message message={item.message} senderName={item.User.name} />
            )}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.messagesContainer}
            inverted
          />
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              value={inputValue}
              onChangeText={handleChange}
              onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
              placeholder="Type a message"
              placeholderTextColor="#999"
              multiline
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit} style={styles.sendButton}>
              <MaterialIcons name="send" size={24} color="#009688" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to parse it?

Comment: Please log `typeof user`. Looks like a JSON string?